# Java - Convert byte[] to char[]. The encoding is UTF-16

Tags: java, arrays, character-encoding, type-conversion, utf-16

I need to convert byte[] to char[] in Java.
The Unicode encoding used is UTF-16.

To be concise, I need a Java equivalent of c#'s

```
UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetChars(byte[] bytes);
```

Also, I need to convert only a part of byte[] to char[]

```
public virtual char[] GetChars(byte[] bytes, int index, int count);
```

Comment: Why did you dislike `UTF-8`? `UTF-16` always occupies at least two bytes unnecessarily (even though it is not absolutely necessary - even though unicode code points fit into a single byte).

Comment: The value i am reading is already encoded in UTF-16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
byte[] b = ...
char[] c = new String(b, "UTF-16").toCharArray();
```

From [`String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.lang.String)):

> Constructs a new `String` by decoding the specified array of bytes using the specified charset.

Answer (score 1):

C# API:

> public virtual char[] GetChars(byte[] bytes);

Java:

> byte[] byte = ...
>
> char[] char = new String(byte, "UTF-16").toCharArray();

Java methods to return char[] :

```
public static char[] getCharsFromBytes(byte[] bytes, String type) {
    try {
        String byteConvert = new String(bytes, "UTF-16");
        return byteConvert.toCharArray();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DataTypeUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

C# API:

> public virtual char[] GetChars(byte[] bytes, int index, int count);

Java:

> Iterate through required bytes in the byte array

```
public static char[] getCharsFromBytes(byte[] bytes, int index, int count) {
    char[] charArr = getCharsFromBytes(bytes);
    char[] result = new char[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result[i] = charArr[i + startIndex];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static char[] GetChars(byte[] bytes, int index, int count) {
    try {
        return new String(java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes,index,index+count), "UTF-16").toCharArray();
    } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        assert false: "Your JRE is broken (UTF-16 not supported)";
        return null;
    }
}
```